# Populating SQLite table with Tcl script in SQLiteStudio

Tags: sqlite, tcl, sqlitestudio

I'm trying to populate two `INTEGER` fields of a table in SQLite Studio with Tcl script feature of [SQLiteStudio](http://sqlitestudio.pl/). The table itself is a representation of a m✕n rectangular matrix, where those two fields represent elements' indices.

```
CREATE TABLE matrix ( i INTEGER NOT NULL, j INTEGER NOT NULL, e REAL );
```

I've tried to recreate a surrogate *for loop* with the following script for the first field:

```
set i 0; #Initialization code
```

```
set i [expr {$i==100?1:$i+1}]; #Per step code
```

and this script for the second one:

```
set j 0; #Initialization code
```

```
set j [expr {$i==100?$j+1:$j}]; #Per step code
```

While the first script populates field `i` normally, the second one displays `Error while executing populating code: can't read "i": no such variable` error message, and the `j` field is populated with `null` values.

Is there any way to use SQLiteStudio's population mechanism this way (i.e. accessing field's new value from scope of another field's population Tcl script)?

**REMARK**

The final solution looked like this:

```
#1st script initialization code
set n_i 10
set i 0
```

```
#1st script per step code
set i [expr {$i%$n_i==0?1:$i+1}]
```

```
#2nd script initialization code
set n_i 10
set i 0
set j 1
```

```
#2nd script per step code
set i [expr {$i%$n_i==0?1:$i+1}]
set j [expr {$i%$n_i==0?$j+1:$j}]
```

It seems, that population Tcl script does not actually care about variable naming, and simply takes the last set variable's value to populate a field for a given row.

Comment: Isn't the first `i` in the second `expr` argument supposed to be a `j`?

Comment: @PeterLewerin No, that's actually what the question about. `i` is not just a variable name, it is also an SQLite table field name, which I'm hoping to access from second script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot share variables between two scripts for populating two different columns (although it's a neat idea), but in your case you should be fine by copying script from first column (the one with `i`) and paste it before your current code for `j`. Sure, you will be calculating `i` twice, but it should get the job done.

Comment: You, sir, are a genius, and I am humbled. And feel oh so dumb right now. Thank you :)